# Как оставить только нижнюю границу у UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Нужно оставить только нижнюю границу у UITextField. Мой код почему то не работает.

```
let bottomLine = CALayer()
bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:1.0, width: myTextField.frame.width, 
height: myTextField.frame.height - 1)
bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
myTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего на момент добавления CALayer размер UITextField не верный. При изменении размеров view только привязанный к нему его CALayer меняет размеры, но на sublayers это не распространяется.
Либо отслеживать изменение размеров UITextField и обновлять положение вашего CALayer, либо проще - добавить UIView как subview с прописанные свойствами его layer. 
Не забудь указать чтоб subview менял размеры согласно его родителю через autoresizingMask.

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin]
```